# MacOS Sierra - no /usr/bin/safaridriver

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver

I am very new to mac and I'm trying to start first selenium script on safari. For all I know, browser extension is not supported anymore and safaridriver should be  defaultly installed by apple, also for MacOS Sierra. According to Apple documentation I should find it in /usr/bin/safaridriver, but on my mac it looks like there's no usr, bin diretories. Also I can't find safaridriver. Is it possible that I don't have those directories at all and webdriver file? I already installed python3, selenium and enabled remote automation in safari browser. But the problem with webdriver remains...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
On Mac desktop: 
click: 'Go' 
Click: 'Go to folder'
Input: '/usr/bin'
Click: 'Go'
```

You bin folder should open, the safari driver is located there